# Ctrl + Alt act like Super for some bindings

Tags: 16.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have a Dell Inspiron 7757 laptop with a factory-installed 16.04. As I used to work on Windows, I tried to change key bindings to more familiar ones. For example, I wanted to use <kbd>Super + L</kbd> to lock the screen and <kbd>Super + D</kbd> to minimize all windows.

I changed key bindings in System Settings app but the desired bindings won't work. Meanwhile when I press <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd>, the workstation locks! It's very annoying because in the software I use (Intellij IDEA) this binding has a different meaning.

The same goes for <kbd>Super + D</kbd>. It doesn't work, but <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + D</kbd> does its work instead.

The most intriguing is that <kbd>Super + T</kbd> which I assigned to 'Launch Terminal' action works properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check *Settings -> Keyboard* to make sure that you don't have multiple keybindings set for each?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked. I also checked the bindings in dconf Editor. There are single values for each.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring related questions here, I found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26224554) on SO. Just install **CompizConfig Settings Manager** and look for additional key bindings in **Ubuntu Unity Plugin** section. You might remove those bindings or change them according to your needs.